# Change indentation with Emacs minor mode

Tags: c++, emacs, minor-mode

I have a CS class that requires (or at least strongly suggests) 8 spaces for C++ indentation. I normally use 2, so this is quite different for me.

I have until recently been just toggling the indent code in my `.emacs` and running `eval-buffer`, but that seems like a poor solution with a programmable editor.

So I am wondering: how might I go about creating a minor Mode (or is there a better function for this?)? I'd like to be able to enable it with `M-x comp-mode` or something similar.

I have seen minor modes, but they seem to instead focus on key mappings. Perhaps I am looking at the wrong Emacs feature.

Perhaps I can extend the C++ mode to create a `comp-mode` with different indentation settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do this with a minor mode, but an easier solution is to use [directory variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html). Create a file called `.dir-locals.el` in the directory containing your coursework and put something like this in it:

```lisp
((c++-mode . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
              (c-basic-offset . 8))))
```

Comment: Does this by chance apply recursively? If so, then holy crap!

Comment: Yes, in general it applies to all subdirectories, although you can specify different rules for individual subdirectories if you wish. Out of the box, `.dir-locals.el` settings do not apply when editing remotely, e.g. using TRAMP. The manual [has more details](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html). Note that I just updated the snippet for `c++-mode` instead of `c-mode`.

Comment: The [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables) has some useful notes on directory (and other) local variables as well.